# How to update/reload table key values

Tags: lua

How can i update a key value using another key value as variable which is inside the same table?

```
local t = {}
t.playerPosition = {x = 0, y = 0, z = 0}
t.positions = {t.playerPosition.x + 1, t.playerPosition.y + 1, t.playerPosition.z + 1}
```

Then few lines later i update **playerPosition**

```
t.playerPosition = {x = 125, y = 50, z = 7}
```

And then if i print out...

result

```
t.positions[1] -- outputs 1
t.positions[2] -- outputs 1
t.positions[3] -- outputs 1
```

expected result

```
t.positions[1] -- outputs 126
t.positions[2] -- outputs 51
t.positions[3] -- outputs 8
```

As you can see key **positions** isnt updating, what could i do to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t.positions = {t.playerPosition.x + 1, t.playerPosition.y + 1, t.playerPosition.z + 1}
```

In the above line, the expressions are evaluated *once*, and the resulting values are assigned to fields of the subtable. After this point, changes to the fields of `t.playerPosition` will not cause a reflected change in `t.positions`.

[Metatables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4) can be used to enable such behaviour, by dynamically calculating results when accessing the fields of `t.positions`.

```lua
local t = {}
t.playerPosition = { x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 }
t.positions = setmetatable({}, {
        __newindex = function () return false end,
        __index = function (_, index)
            local lookup = { 'x', 'y', 'z' }
            local value = t.playerPosition[lookup[index]]

            if value then
                return value + 1
            end
        end
})

print(t.positions[1], t.positions[2], t.positions[3])
t.playerPosition = {x = 125, y = 50, z = 7}
print(t.positions[1], t.positions[2], t.positions[3])
```